# Why my javascript code is failing in performance test cases of code challenge?

Tags: javascript, performance

Code challenge question, my solution and result of test cases can be found in the link below

https://app.codility.com/cert/view/cert7ETU9Q-AA9D2MAVP43AR4WP/details/

Can you please review it and tell why my solution is failing in performance testcases? and how my solution can be improved?

Thanks

Comment: This post belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are computing maxes at every iteration (using `Math.max`), which gives a quadratic time algorithm. However, once you have max of the heights of the first k buildings, you can update it in constant time (is the last building taller than the max?) You can do right to left maxes similarly - this will give you a linear time algorithm for the problem.